# How to avoid/overcome animations on bottom navigation bar on android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, navigationbar, kotlin-android-extensions

The navigation bar has 4 buttons, all of color gray. Each one inflates a specific fragment. when clicked on it,it changes its color to red.

The button which is clicked is also becoming larger(bigger).I want to change the color(gray to red) but not `size`.
How to achieve this (not changing the size of button)?

Thanks in advance.

The following is the part of the code:

**Menu xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_feed"
        android:title=""/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_analytics"
        android:title="" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="" />
</menu>
```

**kotlin code**:

```
private lateinit var bottomnav : BottomNavigationView
val navUtils = NavigationUtils()
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = 
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigation_home -> {
            val locationhistoryinstance = 
            LocationHistoryFragment.newInstance()
            loadFragment(locationhistoryinstance)
            setTitle("Calender Test")
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }

        R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
            val analyticsinstance = AnalyticsPageFragment.newInstance()
            loadFragment(analyticsinstance)
            setTitle("Analytics")
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }

        R.id.navigation_profile -> {
            val profileinstance = ProfileFragment.newInstance()
            loadFragment(profileinstance)
            setTitle("Profile")
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_settings -> {
            val settingsinstance = SettingsFragment.newInstance()
            loadFragment(settingsinstance)
            setTitle("Settings")
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    bottomnav = findViewById(R.id.navigation)

    navUtils.disableShiftMode(bottomnav)

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972293/remove-animation-shifting-mode-from-bottomnavigationview-android

Comment: no this is to disable the shifting mode only, I want it to disable everything

Comment: What do you mean with 'everything'?

Comment: i only want it to change its color not get bigger than the other buttons in size

Comment: Use kotlin answer from @ElegyD [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49013200/6733404). I used and worked fine for me