# How do I override standard Android's BottomNavigation behavior when there are more than 3 buttons

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm testing new Android's BottomNavigationView from support library. The default behavior when there are more than 3 buttons is to expand the selected one while shifting others and hiding their texts. 
I'm wondering, is there way to override this behavior and to distribute the buttons evenly with all the titles visible? Similar to when there are only 3 of them.

Comment: That's agaist design guidelines, so I doubt such feature will be implemented in official library.

Comment: I understand that. But, unfortunately, my client wants it to look like ios one.

Comment: I know that feeling. I suggest you use old tabLayout and set customView for each. That's exactly what I've done many times.

Comment: Thanks. I think it might be a quick solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable BottomNavigationView shift mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode)

Comment: You could use another bottom bar, which displays all tabs completely always: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar