# BottomNavigationView disable shift mode without using reflection

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, bottomnavigationview

[image]

BottomNavigationView doesn't allow disabling shift mode has this issue fixed in new version of support library?

Also there are some solutions which use reflection mechanism I don't think its right way is there any solution to this major problem.

[All ready seen this solution don't want to use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode)

Comment: Looking for a solution to the same problem.

Comment: An alternative is to just ditch the BottomNavigationView from the support lib and write your own layout with a horizontal LinearLayout that contains vertical LinearLayouts with an ImageView and a TextView, and you manage the item selection state.

Answer (score 4):

If possible then update to android sdk-28 then add `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` in your xml.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update to 28.0.0 support library!
They already provided **setLabelVisibilityMode()** method to disable the shifting

```
navButton.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
```

for more info, check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/LabelVisibilityMode.html#LABEL_VISIBILITY_SELECTED

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have face the same problem and I know that its tedious task to load  reflect java library in xamarin android.

But thanks to "**James Montemagno**" to come with its solution. Here is the link you can follow and got the result you want!

It worked for me hope it will for you too. Happy coding! :)

Link: **https://montemagno.com/remove-shifting-bottomnavigationview-android/**

Git Post: **https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin-Templates/blob/master/Xamarin.Android-Templates/Projects/BottomTabsApp/BlankAppCompat/BottomNavigationViewUtils.cs**

public static class BottomNavigationViewUtils
    {

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Enable or disable shift mode on bottom navigation view
    /// </summary>

    public static void SetShiftMode(this BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView, bool enableShiftMode, bool enableItemShiftMode)
    {
        try
        {
            var menuView = bottomNavigationView.GetChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView;
            if (menuView == null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to find BottomNavigationMenuView");
                return;
            }


            var shiftMode = menuView.Class.GetDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");

            shiftMode.Accessible = true;
            shiftMode.SetBoolean(menuView, enableShiftMode);
            shiftMode.Accessible = false;
            shiftMode.Dispose();


            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var item = menuView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
                if (item == null)
                    continue;

                item.SetShiftingMode(enableItemShiftMode);
                item.SetChecked(item.ItemData.IsChecked);

            }

            menuView.UpdateMenuView();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to set shift mode: {ex}");
        }
    }
}
```

Than Use it:

var bottomNavigationView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.bottomNavigationBar);
 bottomNavigationView.SetShiftMode(false,false);

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Here, posting a link is not enough, please ensure that your answer will be useful in the future if those links are not working anymore: quote the relevant parts of the pages **inside your post**.

Comment: This uses reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your dimens.. worked for me!

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size">12sp</dimen>
```