# BottomNavigationView getmaxitemcount

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

Hello member stackoverflow 
 porblem with bottomnavihationview

in my app I used  BottomNavigationView  with 4 item . it make my app easy and beauty

```
  BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
        bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.action_one:

                        break;
                    case R.id.action_two:
                        FragmentTransaction manger= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        pop_web_view  pop3 =new pop_web_view();
                        pop3.show(manger,null);

                        break;
                    case R.id.action_three:

                        break;
                    case R.id.action_four:

                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

in activity_main :

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="560dp"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorDivider"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />
```

in menu xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_one"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_secure"
        android:title="One"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_two"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:title="Two"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_three"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:title="Three"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_four"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_popup_reminder"
        android:title="Four"/>
</menu>
```

BUT I have problem Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Maximum number of items supported by BottomNavigationView is 5. Limit can be checked with BottomNavigationView#getMaxItemCount()
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@chornenkyy.v/first-look-at-bottomnavigationview-from-android-design-library-8244de85b953#.jae121tmp

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error said that maximum number of items supported by `BottomNavigationView` is 5.

And try to delete

`bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom_navigation);`

because you are already inflating it in
`app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"`

And you are modifying it by calling

`bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom_navigation);`

The documentation says **Existing items in the menu will not be modified or removed.**

Check this [documention](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#inflateMenu(int))

And check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40189977/5962715)

**Implementation of BottomNavigationView has condition: when there is more than 3 items then use shift mode.**

Comment: i  have 4 item just

Comment: @AyhamShowa the code you are posted here is of menu_bottom_navigation.xml?

Comment: this is a cod for menu_bottom_navigation.xml

Comment: @AyhamShowa then try deleting `bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom_navigation);` from your code.

Comment: @AyhamShowa Which animation are you talking about?

Comment: when i press item it move to left 
But know it stop

Comment: @AyhamShowa check that answer which I added to my answer

Comment: but this for disableShiftMode !!

Comment: @AyhamShowa try to add these in your code `item.setShiftingMode(true);` and `item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());`

Comment: where i add this ??

Comment: @AyhamShowa after the switch statement `switch (id){`

Comment: @AyhamShowa then remove `item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());` and try with `item.setShiftingMode(true);`

Comment: where i can add photo ?

Comment: @AyhamShowa can you caopy that `BottomNavigationViewHelper` from that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40189977/5962715) and replace `item.setShiftingMode(false);` to `item.setShiftingMode(true);` and apply to your code like `BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);` beacause this item is bottomNavigationView item and that is `BottomNavigationMenuView` item

Answer (score 4):

I know you accepted the current answer, but it's incomplete.
You added a menu in your XML to the `BottomNavigationView`, then you try to call `inflateMenu(...)`, however, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#inflateMenu(int)) clearly says:

> Existing items in the menu will not be modified or removed.

This means that you are *adding* menu items to this view, not replacing them.

What you can do to fix it is the following:

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().clear();
bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom_navigation);
```

Also it's worth mentioning that you do the same things twice: once in the XML (by adding `app:menu="..."` attribute to the layout item), once in the Java class by calling the `inflateMenu(...)` method. Delete either of them and it will work. Keep in mind though that if you want to change the menu items later dynamically, you'll need to clear the existing items the way I posted.

Comment: @AyhamShowa What did you change exactly?

Comment: remove this :
bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom_navigation);

Comment: @AyhamShowa If you remove the XML attribute instead of this, does the animation work?

Answer (score 0):

In my app I used BottomNavigationView with 2 item, but there are 4 items like this:
[image: duplicate items]

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_constraintlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    tools:context=".BottomNavigation">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my code:

```
public class BottomNavigation extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "BottomNavigation";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_navigation);
            updateMenu();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: ", e);;
        }
    }

    @UiThread
    private void updateMenu() {
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        if (bottomNavigationView != null) {
            bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.navigation);

            for (Integer i = 0;
                 i < bottomNavigationView.getMenu().size();
                 ++i   ) {
                Log.i(TAG, "updateMenu: " + bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getItemId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Delete either of them and it will work. thanks.