# Remove padding for icons in bottom navigation view

Tags: android, navigationview, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to make the icons in a bottom navigation view lower. For example, right now they are pressed against the top line like this.

[image: See image here]

How would I make the icon lower? I want them to be centered vertically in the bottom navigation view.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.jchousurface.mastertrack.homescreen">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml code please ?

Comment: Sure, its nothing special though, just the basic navigation view

Comment: @Glory just edited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable BottomNavigationView shift mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode)

Answer (score 3):

use

```
bottomNavigationView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_UNLABELED);
```

or

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

Answer (score 0):

change `attribute android:layout_height="40dp"` or lower in `BottomNavigationView`