# BottomNavigationView should look like the Youtube App

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I want to create a BottomNavigationView Screen like YouTube but I'm facing an issue that view is not displaying like that.

It perfectly works with three bottom menus but when I'm using more than three menus then **Its Title is hiding and menus are shifted.** I'm not understanding why this happening, I had tried many tricks but not solve the problem.

[image]

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Java Activity:

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);

// I had tried this code but not working

//   BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) 
//   bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
//            bottomNavigationView.setAnimation(null);
//            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
//                BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
//                itemView.setShiftingMode(false);
//                itemView.setChecked(false);
//            }
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

Anyone, please suggest how I can achieve this.

Comment: Hi @Garg's, please read this: https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html. Hope this help!

Comment: And try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode

Comment: @SonhnLab thanks, buddy...

Answer (score 0):

By default android makes only selected item title appearing on more than three menu items. If you do not want this to happen set BottomNavigationView XML atribute app:labelVisibility to labeled.

Answer (score 0):

Add These property to your BottomNavigationView in XML.

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```