# How to enable BottomNavigationView's shifting mode

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

Its not duplicate of [How to disable BottomNavigationView shift mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode)

I'm using `BottomNavigationView` in my application but `Shifting Mode` not works , just shows ripple with no animation !

I tested this code but not helped !

```
 BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) navigation.getChildAt(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
    item.setShifting(true);
  }
```

```java
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

my xml :

```xml
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/blue_grey_700"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation_shifting" />
```

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfyLl.gif)
and
[my result !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bBI5.gif)

Comment: In design:28.0.0 animation not work ! works with 27 :(

Answer (score 0):

Sifting mode is your default one. You no need to active shifting mode. If you want to remove shifting mode then you have to do some modification.

If you did any modification on `BottomNavigationView` object then remove it and try again.

Comment: I know , but that's not active by default for me !
see the above videos  .