# Bottom Navigation mShiftedMode Not found

Tags: android

```
2019-05-30 14:37:58.684 24598-24598/com.tokr.com E/BNVHelper: Unable to get shift mode field
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mShiftingMode in class Landroid/support/design/internal/BottomNavigationMenuView; (declaration of 'android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView' appears in /data/app/com.tokr.com-d7oEdvg1K1YZW81hAgZt5w==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
    at com.tokr.com.util.BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationViewHelper.kt:12)
    at com.tokr.com.ui.base.BaseActivity.handleBottomNav(BaseActivity.kt:272)
    at com.tokr.com.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:168)
    at com.tokr.com.ui.base.BaseLocationActivity.onCreate(BaseLocationActivity.java:32)
    at com.tokr.com.ui.home.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:146)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation and pass your `Activity` code.

Comment: Which API level are you using?

Comment: Apparently, you are using reflection to get a non-existent field, that's what the stack trace is telling

Comment: If you are trying to disable the shifting mode in the `BottomNavigationView`, I think you will find your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode