# Cannot resolve method 'item.setShiftingMode(false);'

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to disable shift mode of bottom navigation bar but getting the above error.I'm following this link [How to disable BottomNavigationView shift mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode) for tutorial.
Here is my code:

```
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51147002/7666442

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable BottomNavigationView shift mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode)

Comment: @NileshRathod I followed the same tutorial but it is now throwing the error, I mentioned above.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk  Not Exactly.

Comment: @PraveenGupta can you show your gradle file and device information that you use?

Comment: I'm using onePlus 7 pro.

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
}`

Comment: And i'm getting this error: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference"