# Disable reselecting in BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android

How can I disable reloading fragment when clicking again on the current tab in `BottomNavigationView`?

In other words how to disable re-selection in `BottomNavigationView`?

PS: I'm using `NavigationUI` to setup `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode)

Comment: @JimaleAbdi This disables shifting mode not reclicking, I want to disable reclick so if I'm in the home fragment and click on home tab nothing happens

Comment: I have disabled the reloading BottomNavigationView on clicking it again but not with Navigation UI. we have to load the fragments in the start and we need to hide other fragments on click of a particular tab. It's working fine for me.

Comment: @BrahmaDatta Can you please provide an example?

Comment: sure @MohammadHoseinKalantarian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was surprisingly simple!

```
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, hostNavController);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            // Nothing here to disable reselect
        }
    });
```

Comment: Remember you have to do it after "setupWithNavController"

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for an up-to-date implementation in **Kotlin**:

```kotlin
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavigationBar, navController)
binding.bottomNavigationBar.setOnItemReselectedListener {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know Mohammad Hosein,

```
final Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
final Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
final Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3();
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment active = fragment1; //make the first screen as your active fragment.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment1, "1").commit();

}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.f1_menu_item:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                active = fragment1;
                return true;

            case R.id.f2_menu_item:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                active = fragment2;
                return true;

            case R.id.f3_menu_item:
               fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
              active = fragment3;

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

And in activity_main.xml,

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FBF9F9"
tools:context=".view.HomeScreenActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/main_container">

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

let me know if you stuck anywhere Hosein. And accept the answer if this works.

Comment: awesome answer, tnx ...

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin code looks like this:

```
 val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

 navView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { 
    // do nothing here when reselected
    }
```