# Android BottomNavigationView unselected text not showing

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am using android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.  All is fine except the titles not showing when not selected.

[image]

```
<!-- layout -->
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bnvBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

<!-- theme -->
<style name="BottomNavigationTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
</style>
```

What is missing?

Comment: check this--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718633/bottomnavigationview-with-more-than-3-items-tab-title-is-hiding

Comment: try this -  bottomNavigationView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED) @Sean

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you are using Support Library 28 Try this,

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

Full code

```xml
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bnvBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" 
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    />
```

Comment: thanks man. 
you just saved my day. I was going through different forums to get an answer to this .