# How to create android button bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I need to create a horizontal list of buttons without a separating space like this one [image] [image: buttonbar]
each button will contain a text and an icon I know about buttonbarlayout but it didn't work for me, please can someone help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: Create custom tab bar .https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Answer (score 6):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/read"
        android:text="Rewards" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/read"
        android:text="Places" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/read"
        android:text="Challenges" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and three buttons with layout_weight=1

Answer (score 3):

There is **BottomNavigationView** element for this

in your layout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/navigation"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="56dp"
 android:layout_gravity="start"
 app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

res/menu/my_navigation_items.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/menu_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_navigation"
          android:title="@string/menu_navigation"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:id="@+id/func"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_next">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_bgm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3279CE"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pager_image"
            android:text="BitRate"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3279CE"
            android:text="time"
            />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_effect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3279CE"
            android:text="effect" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3279CE"
            android:text="FRAME" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's so similar to what I want to do, I just have an issue:I want that the icon and the text will be next to each other and in the center of the button   |------ Text +Icon ------ |

Comment: @Caroline, no problem, just use `android:drawableRight="@drawable/..."` to put a drawable to the right of the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
private LinearLayout tabLayout; 

   FrameLayout tab1 = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_cell, null);
    tab1.findViewById(R.id.click_view).setOnClickListener(this);
    tab1.findViewById(R.id.click_view).setTag(First_TAB);
    textviewone = (TextView) tab1.findViewById(R.id.tab_header);
    textviewone.setWidth(SMALL_TAB_WIDTH);
    textviewone.setText("Rewards");
    textviewone.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.picture_s, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.addView(tab1);

    FrameLayout tab2 = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_cell,, null);
    tab2.findViewById(R.id.click_view).setOnClickListener(this);
    tab2.findViewById(R.id.click_view).setTag(Second_TAB);
    secondtab = (TextView) tab2.findViewById(R.id.tab_header);
    secondtab.setWidth(SMALL_TAB_WIDTH);
    secondtab.setText(R.string.roster);
    secondtab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icon_selector_s, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.addView(tab2);

    FrameLayout tab3 = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_cell, null);
    tab3.findViewById(R.id.click_view).setOnClickListener(this);
    tab3.findViewById(R.id.click_view).setTag(Third_TAB);
    thirdtab = (TextView) tab3.findViewById(R.id.tab_header);
    thirdtab.setWidth(SMALL_TAB_WIDTH);
    thridtab.setText(R.string.copy_entry);
    thridtab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.select_activity_selector_s, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.addView(tab3);
```

tab_cell.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_header"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="10.5sp"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/click_view"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Below is the linear layout in the activity declared as tabLayout in the code:

```
 <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabs" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="10"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have added it. Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

What you can see in that picture isn't a simple button bar, it's called **Bottom Navigation Bar**, and Android has specific code for that. [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar) you can learn how to create one and use it. You can change of course the colors with simple XML or Java code. Hope you find it helpful.