# Bottom Navigation View With Left Righ Space Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I am newbie in android, i am use bottom navigation view with two menus

but im getting left right space

Here is my Navigation View,

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        app:itemBackground="@color/colorRed"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_menu"/>
```

Please check Image
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to Material design guidelines
You can't use two menus with bottom navigation use, instead of bottomNavigation view use tab layout 
Check this link for guidlines https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage

Still, if you want to use bottom navigation view

Try This inside **BottomNavigationView**

```
android:background="@color/colorRed"
```

Comment: Thanks ! let me check with this

Comment: I'm using four menus but still facing the same space issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Inside BottomAppBar set attribute

```
android:padding="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are fewer than three destinations, consider using tabs instead.
In Bottom

Comment: If you want to implement the Bottom Navigation bar then from start or create a new project with navigation bar Activity , this activity give by default bottom navigation bar implemented......  Or follow this link                                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar