# Create Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to make a bottom navigation bar that changes the activity based on the button but whenever I try the tutorials there is one error or another

Comment: Android Studio (2.3) mostly likely isn't the problem. Please post your errors

Comment: What are the errors you are receiving?

Comment: Hi , i think using bottom navigation bar for changing the activity would be bad idea, use fragments instead.You can try the activity template of bottom navigation in android studio.

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can use this library for bottomnavifationbar**

[github lib](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) ,
 [github lib 2](https://github.com/sephiroth74/Material-BottomNavigation) ,
 [githublib 3](https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar),
 [github lib 4](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation),

**or
try this**

**complie this depedencie**

```
compile ‘com.android.support:design:25.3.1’
```

create a layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Content Container -->

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**create menu as per your reqirement**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/text_favorites"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/text_schedules"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_music"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/text_music"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

```
**Handling Enabled / Disabled states. Make selector file.**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

**handle click events**

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_favorites:

                    break;
                case R.id.action_schedules:

                    break;
                case R.id.action_music:

                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if You want something as a nav bar You should try getting to GitHub because there are many great things there like:
https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu

Try it, looks way better than a simple nav bar.
cheers

Answer (score -1):

The official is no longer supported, so you can try [radiobutton](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) and [viewpager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: False information : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

Comment: i get it ,so thank you for your suggestion and hope more communication with you 。

Comment: @reTs the link you provided 404's

Comment: @cren90 It's not a 404 for now but seems that the layout is broken.

Comment: I'm not getting 404 on it anymore either.