# Fixed Bottom Navigation Bar using BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-design, bottomnavigationview

I want to create a fixed bottom navigation bar instead of a shifting navigation bar (which is the default provided by the BottomNavigationView)  using BottomNavigationView. So, how should I create it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155551/create-bottom-navigation-bar/45158913#45158913

Comment: Follow this guidline and you can create your bottomnavigationview exactly like the one android provides. I created mine following this.
https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#