# Change bottom icon when move from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-icons, android-bottomnav

I have a main activity with bottom nav and a frame layout to hold each fragment I have made for the numbers of icon in my botton nav. I have a fragment page in which i have a text and want to change the fragment and also the bottom nav icon from the click action on text.

Comment: please add some codes

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to below links :

[Android new Bottom Navigation bar or BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar-or-bottomnavigationview)

[How to Code a Bottom Navigation Bar for an Android App](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-bottom-navigation-bar-for-an-android-app--cms-30305)

[Android Working with Bottom Navigation](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/)