# Modulation by tab in android Java

Tags: android, android-studio, module, navigation

I have been building my first android App with 5 tabs in Android studio. I am planning to breakdown my tabs from 1 module into 5 modules in order to clear cut each functionality.

My problem is, I am figuring out how to make the connection among modules such that I can change tabs and run its functions based on different modules. Anyone has come across this problem before? Any good reference/resource for me to study as beginner?

[image: main activity with tabs]

[Edit]

This is what I want to achieve. Breakdown tabs at project level (by module)

[image: want to achieve]

Comment: You can use BottomNavigationView to achieve this functionality. Please refer to this question on stackoverflow to find answer for your question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar-or-bottomnavigationview

Comment: Thx Massab,  I have achieved that by using the bottom NAV bar as you can see in the screen. What i mean is to breakdown the tabs at project level. Please see attached screen for your reference