# Android Tabs in the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-tabs

Hi I want to display tabs in the bottom of the screen with icon above the text in each tab(similar like zomato),i have tried but i am not getting the icons and text.can you please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Please post all the things you have tried so far!!!

Comment: I think It is not a tab. I just a menu.

Comment: Just add `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in manifest. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18944930/5241603

Answer (score 2):

You can use below library to achieve  [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)

**[Update]**

Now google released [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) to achieve your requirement.
This class is a part of support design library.
add gradle dependency

```
compile ‘com.android.support:design:25.0.0’
```

Add layout file in your xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

create bottom_navigation_main.xml file which included in above layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_favorites"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_schedules"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_music"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

and finally use this layout in java class like below

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_favorites:

                        break;
                    case R.id.action_schedules:

                        break;
                    case R.id.action_music:

                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```