# how to add split actionbar to my existing code

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add split `actionbar` to my existing `actionbar` that gets displayed at the top of the screen, so that I can display those tabs at the bottom

```
ActionBar ab;
ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


Tab tab = ab
        .newTab()
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_ab_dialpad)
        //.setText("DialPad")
        .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<DialerFragment>(this, "DialPad",
                DialerFragment.class));
ab.addTab(tab);

tab = ab
        .newTab()
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_ab_history_holo_dark)
        //.setText("Recents")
        .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<CallLogListFragment>(this, "Recents",
                CallLogListFragment.class));
ab.addTab(tab);

/*tab = ab
        .newTab()
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_contacts)
        //.setText("Contacts")
        .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<ContactListFragment>(this, "Contacts",
                ContactListFragment.class));
ab.addTab(tab);*/

/*tab = ab
        .newTab()
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_services)
        //.setText("Services")
        .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<ServicesFragment>(this, "Services",
                ServicesFragment.class));
ab.addTab(tab);*/

tab = ab
        .newTab()
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_voicemail)
        //.setText("Settings")
        .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<VoiceMailFragment>(this, "Settings",
                VoiceMailFragment.class));
ab.addTab(tab);
```

At present, these tabs are at the top. how do i make this into a split `actionbar`?
I want to display these main tabs at the bottom and two other tabs at the top

Comment: First You have to Learn Pure Android : http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

inside your activity tag where you want to split actionbar if API version is 14 or higher

otherwise add

```
<meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

inside `<activity> and </activity>` if API version is lower than 14.

for example:

```
   <manifest ...>
    <activity uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ... >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
</manifest>
```

And [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) is the guide on how to split actionbar.

Comment: Hi karan. Thanks for the information. Can you tell me how to mention which tabs to include at the top and which at the bottom? Getting really confused here. I mean where do I specify this?

Comment: With split ActionBar you can only display action items at the bottom, not tabs.

Comment: Okay. Is there any other way to display tabs at bottom ?

Comment: [Check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)