# TabHost Fragment with ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Is it possible to add a tabhost in an activity that has an action bar ?
I want it to look like this:

```
|--------------------------------------|
|< Title      ActionBar        Settings|
|--------------------------------------|
|                                      | 
|                                      | 
|                                      | 
|                                      | 
|          Tab 1 Content               | 
|                                      | 
|                                      | 
|                                      | 
|                                      | 
|--------------------------------------|
|    Tab 1  |   Tab 2     |   Tab 3    |  
|--------------------------------------|
```

The reason I don't want to use ActionBar tabs because they do not support bottom tabs. I am using bottom tabs as mentioned in this question here:
[Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

And I still want to use ActionBar.

Can this be done ?

**Edit:**

Here is the code I am using

```
public class TabsFragment extends Fragment {
    public TabsFragment() {
    }

    private TabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Timeline.TimelineFragment.class);

         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_host, container, false);
         mTabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
         mTabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("my tab content");
        tab.setIndicator("my tab content");
        tab.setContent(i);
        mTabHost.addTab(tab);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        return view;

    }
}
```

And TimelineFragment. The fragment_timeline.xml contains normal views.

```
public static class TimelineFragment extends Fragment {

    public TimelineFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timeline, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And this is the activity that is called on launch:

```
public class TabsFragmentActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs_fragment);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new TabsFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tabs, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

This code is giving me error:

```
05-02 20:04:14.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2884): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
05-02 20:04:14.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2884):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:747)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. TabHost is a regular view. As long as you don't need a (deprecated) TabActivity to show multiple activities as the tabs, you can add tabs using instances of the [TabContentFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabContentFactory.html) interface.

A **very** simple example would be something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_control_layout);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        final String tabText = "Content of tab number " + i;
        TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + i);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab number " + i);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
        {
            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                TextView tabContent = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                tabContent.setText(tabText);
                return tabContent;
            }

        });

        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

However, you should check [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html).

> **Don't use bottom tab bars**
>
> Other platforms use the bottom tab bar to switch between the app's
>   views. Per platform convention, Android's tabs for view control are
>   shown in action bars at the top of the screen instead. In addition,
>   Android apps may use a bottom bar to display actions on a split action
>   bar.
>
> You should follow this guideline to create a consistent experience
>   with other apps on the Android platform and to avoid confusion between
>   actions and view switching on Android.

Comment: I know that I am not supposed to use bottom tabs on Android, but even some apps like instagram do that. I added the code and it is giving me some error.

Comment: I see, you are trying to add Activties as tabs. That's why I mentioned the TabActivity thing. I don't think that's possible, because ActionBarActivity is not derived from TabActivity (plus LocalActivityManager is deprecated). If it's feasible for you, use a TabContentFactory for each tab instead. We have used that in our project without problems.

Comment: Is there a code example on how to do it and still have an actionbar ?

Comment: If i want to inflate an xml i should handle all the listeners in the overrided method ? Does it work well in your project ?

Comment: Yes, we've had no problems with it.