# How to show tabs on bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-tabhost

I have `Fragment` class on which i want to add 3 tabs on the **bottom** of the screen. Below code is showing tab on upper part of the screen. Please help me find out the solution.

Here is my **code:**

```
public class NewVehicleFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentTabHost tabHost;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.fragment_new_vehicle);

    Bundle car = new Bundle();
    car.putInt("arg for car", 1);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Car"),
            NewsFragment.class, car);

    Bundle bike = new Bundle();
    bike.putInt("arg for bike", 2);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Bike"),
            NewsFragment.class, bike);

    Bundle cycle = new Bundle();
    cycle.putInt("arg for cycle", 3);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Cycle"),
            NewsFragment.class, cycle);

    return tabHost;
   }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom

Comment: yes i watch ... please read carefully my question im implementing on  **Fragment**

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip , it is an widget that can be added to your layout at your will, no matter top or bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Lzzy Leung thanks for the suggestion i'll implement it, but for now i need help on this situation.