# How can i add TabView android at the bottom of activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My question is that how i can i add andorid TabView at the bottom of activity,i'm using the following link of code http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/.
I'm provided here the source code of little bit understanding you want,but for more detail please follow this link above,
my activity_main.xml

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

My main.java code is

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

}
```

This has to done by using the fragment activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom

Comment: check this https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: Check this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your layout, first

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/new_divider_bottom_gray"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgorund_gray_color" />


</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```