# How to make filter tab like flipkart in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, filter

I am building an android application. Where I need to implement tab list like Flipkart Filter menu style. Below is image like I want to implement in my application to.

[image].

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2710404/3110234

Comment: @activesince93 that is complete different question.

Comment: am also trying that have you got any solution please post me

Comment: Did you get any more library or solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use two list view horizontally in a LinerLayout like this and make the list view customize according to your need.

Hope it will useful..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <!--  this list contains products -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```