# how to achieve ViewPager with bottom tabs

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager, tripadvisor

i want to achieve this

[image]

i already made this

[image]

Problem :

i made Fragment include 3 tabs

i want to put 2 tabs in the bottom like tripAdvisor

xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)  will help you.

Comment: @Akashbhatt-Aks4125- \\ thnx alot for that .. it helps
but i have problem .. am working with viewPager but your solution works with FrameLayout
so .. it doesn't work for ME :(