# Tabs with view pages and different fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, viewpagerindicator

I want to create 4 tabs at bottom , at which the first tab should show seperate view pages and other tabs should show different fragment attached to it. is it possible?

Comment: It is possible. Go and *Google* it.

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: refer this link
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: There's a library that does EXACTLY that and even more: https://github.com/Aspsine/FragmentNavigator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)